# Git has bug when merging multiple conflict files?

Tags: git

I recently moved my project from CVS to Git because it sounds popular. However I'm quite disappointed when I was trying to merge major branches. In simple, there are two major branches, master and quickfix. The master has 4 commits from the branch point; the quickfix has 15 commits so these two branches have loads of different codes. So I decided to merge them to make life easier. Checked out the master branch I typed

```
ezthumb$ git merge quickfix
Auto-merging eznotify.c
Auto-merging ezthumb.c
Auto-merging ezthumb.h
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in ezthumb.h
Auto-merging main.c
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

It only merged one file. Apparently there should be more, because

```
ezthumb$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   ChangeLog
#   modified:   Makefile
#   modified:   ezgui.c
#   modified:   eznotify.c
#   modified:   ezthumb.1
#   modified:   ezthumb.c
#   modified:   ezthumb.lsm
#   new file:   ezthumb.pdf
#   modified:   id_lookup.c
#   modified:   libsmm/libsmm.h
#   modified:   libsmm/main.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_chdir.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_codepage.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_cwd_alloc.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_cwd_pop.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_cwd_push.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_filesize.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_fstat.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_init.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_mbstowcs.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_pathtrek.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_pwuid.c
#   modified:   libsmm/smm_wcstombs.c
#   modified:   main.c
#   modified:   version.c
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      ezthumb.h
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   output.map
```

I modified the ezthumb.h and git commit -a  to repository. It became more troublesome. Now Git believe these two branches has been merged successfully so refuse to accept any further merge command. Actually there were still over ten different files at large. It took me two hours to find out how to get rid of the wrong merging. I set up a small project trying to confirm the capablity of Git in multiple file merging. It worked quite fine:

```
testproj$ git merge quickfix
Auto-merging fixtoken.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in fixtoken.c
Auto-merging misc.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in misc.c
Auto-merging rename.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in rename.c
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

The result was what I looked forward: Git marked out the conflicts in these files so I can merge them manually. It sounds quite buggy to me that Git have different behaviour in two projects. I have googled two nights for this issue, nothing alike. Is there anyone know how to workaround this? Surely I can diff and merge files manually one by one, but will make it senseless for a version control system. My Git is 1.7.4.4 in Fedora 14.

Comment: What about the output from your first merge makes you think git only merged one file? The merge updated 26 files. 5 of which required a merge. 1 of those could not be automatically resolved.

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure most of these files can not be fast forwarded. What's more, after the 'fake' merge, a 'git diff quickfix' command still display hugh differences even though Git showed nothing can be merged. That's why I'm wondering if it is a bug of Git.

Comment: At no point in any of your output is git saying nothing can be merged. Across both of your merge attempts, a total of 4 files had conflicts. Those conflicts aside, nothing appears to have gone wrong here. Apologies if I've not understood...

Comment: So it seems like your problem is that git is too good at automatically merging files, and so you're confused that it's not prompting you for merging those "over ten other files". Or those files were never checked in.


Could you paste in the relevant lines of `git log --oneline --name-status --graph`

Comment: When I was typing 'pretty sure', I was hit by something in mind. I seemed git diff quickfix and saw many differences. Was that before or after merging? So I went to the committed files and reviewed them line by line. You are quite right, MatW. Git indeed surprisingly merged around a thounsand lines and only hit by one conflict line! I had been expecting hundreds lines manual works. Actually I'm used to doing that in CVS. It take me out of surprise that things could be done in that way. Many thanks to every one for your kindly help.

Comment: Thanks forivall. Yes, I think that's exactly what happened to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, use `git mergetool`. It's much more friendly for newcomers to git.

Comment: Just tried the mergetool. The problem persists because Git only find one conflict file.

> ezthumb$ git mergetool
> merge tool candidates: meld opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff > tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse ecmerge p4merge araxis emerge vimdiff
Merging:
ezthumb.h

Normal merge conflict for 'ezthumb.h':
  {local}: modified
  {remote}: modified
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (meld): meld

ezthumb$ git mergetool
merge tool candidates: meld opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse ecmerge p4merge araxis emerge vimdiff
No files need merging

Comment: @user2023470 The error message is difficult to read in your comment. Please edit your original question so that we can continue to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any bug. Without any more details, I can only guess that the merge was successful on all but one of your files. The output states that git was unable to automatically merge ezthumb.h. This is because both branches have changes to the same line (or lines) in that file. You need to open the file and edit it the way you want it to appear after the merge. Then do a regular `git add` and then a `git commit`.

Comment: Thanks Code-Guru. You are right about the issue. See my post to MatW. Now I feel much confident in git merge.